# adb touchscreen swipe fail in a call

Tags: java, android, automation, adb

I'm trying to simulate a auto video call with adb using touches and swipes.
The scenario:

Device1 audio calls Device2, Device2 answers, Device1 asks for video call(bidirectional), Device2 tries to answer and fails.
The wired thing is that sometimes it works but most of the it fails on that point when the device2 trying to answer via adb swipe.

here is the code:

```
@Test(timeout = 60000000)
    /**
     *
     */
    @TestProperties(name = "Video call / Normal video call")
    public void VT111_0011() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
        initTestVariable("Normal_Video_Call_Test_VT111_0011");
        sleep(idleBeforeTest);
        System.out.println("Starting normal video test");
        Android.adbCommand(secondDevice.getDevice1(), "adb -s " + secondDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input touchscreen swipe 355 858 590 858");

        for(int i=0; i<Iteration; i++) {
            moveMouse();
            Jsystem.broadCastMessage("\nIteration " + i, globalVar.nameForLogFile);
            cleanLogs();
            firstDevice.call(secondDevice);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if(secondDevice.isRinging())
                secondDevice.answerCall(1000);
            else{
                ringingFail();
            }

            // Start video by gui
            Android.adbCommand(firstDevice.getDevice1(),"adb -s " + firstDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input tap 650 380");
            Android.adbCommand(firstDevice.getDevice1(),"adb -s " + firstDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input tap 420 470");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Android.adbCommand(firstDevice.getDevice1(),"adb -s " + firstDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input tap 197 780"); // 197 920 Video bidirectional
            Thread.sleep(5500);
            // Device2 answers video
            Android.adbCommand(firstDevice.getDevice1(),"adb -s " + firstDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input tap 355 858"); // 197 920 Video bidirectional
            Android.adbCommand(secondDevice.getDevice1(), "adb -s " + secondDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input touchscreen swipe 355 858 590 858");
            Thread.sleep(200);
            Android.adbCommand(firstDevice.getDevice1(),"adb -s " + firstDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input tap 60 372");
            Android.adbCommand(secondDevice.getDevice1(),"adb -s " + secondDevice.getDeviceID() + " shell input tap 60 372");


        /*  Thread.sleep(5000);
            if((!firstDevice.isInCall()) || (!secondDevice.isInCall())){
                inCallFail();
                continue;
            } */
            int failsCounter = 0;
            VerifyVideo verifyVideo = new VerifyVideo(); 
            for(int j = 8; j<10; j++){
                if(verifyVideo.verrfiyVideo(firstDevice, secondDevice) == false)
                    failsCounter++;
            }
            if(failsCounter>2) {
                Jsystem.broadCastMessage("****** TEST FAILED, VIDEO DOSENT WORK GOOD ENOUGH ****** " , globalVar.nameForLogFile); 
                System.out.println("Number of fails: " + failsCounter);
                comparePhototsFail();
            }

            firstDevice.endCall();
            secondDevice.endCall();
            sleep(TimeBetweenIteration);

        }

    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "tries to answer and fails"? What do you see on the device itself? If you try to answer manually a video call, do you ALWAYS success?

Comment: When I run this code, secoundDevice tries to answer there is a popup massage "unfortunately phone has stopped" and there is no video... When I do the same scenario manually it works every time.

Answer (score 1):

Try add duration to swipe:

```
adb shell input touchscreen swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)]
```